# Is there a way to get the `id` of a nested_form field helper element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am trying to create the `for` attribute for a label in a nested form (Using nested_form). Is there a way to get the `id` of a corresponding `f.checkbox`?

HAML:

```
= label_tag '???', "Set as On",  class: primary_btn
= f.check_box :is_on
```

Additional Information:
The current Model structure is like `Post` has many `Images` with field `is_on`

So I would like to create a nested field group like:

```
  <label class="primary_btn" for="post_images_attributes_0_is_on">Set as primary</label>
  <input id="post_images_attributes_0_is_on" name="post[images_attributes][0][is_on]" style="display:none;" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

Comment: Why aren't you just using `f.label`?

Comment: Do you mean "How do I set the ID attribute of a label?"?

Comment: @japed It maybe the way I've used it but it doesn't work for `nested_form`: When I use `= label :is_on, 'set as primary', class: 'primary_btn'` It became: `<label class="primary_btn" for="is_on_set as primary">Set as primary</label>`. The id of the checkbox should be: `post_images_attributes_0_is_on`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use `fields_for`. It gives you a "scoped" form builder instance which creates inputs for the nested fields.

```
= form_for (:post) do |f| 
    # ... a bunch of fields
    = f.fields_for :images do |builder|
        = builder.label :is_on, "Set as primary"
        = builder.check_box :is_on
```

However your solution has some real gotchas:

- Every time you change the primary image you need to update  all the `post.images` to ensure that only one image has the `is_on` flag.
- You need to do `primary_image = post.images.where(is_on: true)`
- It won't work if the image can belong to many posts.

A better solution is create a special relation to the primary image on Post.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  has_one :primary_image, class_name: 'Image'
end
```

This would store the primary image as an integer in `posts.primary_image_id` instead of as a boolean flag on `images`.

We can use `collection_select` to get select tag to display the primary image attribute.

```
= form_for (@post) do |f| 
    # ... a bunch of fields
    = f.fields_for :images do |builder|
        # ...
  = f.collection_select(:primary_image, @post.images, :id, :name)
```

This admittedly is not really optimal from a user experience perspective. A solution which requires javascript would be to have a hidden field for `:primary_image` and update its value when the user clicks the checkbox. If you are unsure how to do this please create a new question since its out of the scope of your original question.

Comment: Again please don't ask me how link the inputs in the comments. Create a new question. You will get better feedback from more people and it's out of scope since its a totally new starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Great comment on the data structure as well!

Comment: Just a comment for others who may look into this in the future. The problem of my code is that I have not use the form builder: `f.label`